# Redirecting redis client to slave if master is under a large transaction (redis cluster) and vice versa

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to implement a 3 master 3 slave architecture with redis cluster. I want to redirect my client to slave if master is blocked (like undergoing a `MULTI EXEC` query) or redirect to master if slave is synchronising the `MULTI EXEC` query. Is there any way I can achieve it through redis configuration, or do I need to manually implement this logic with the client library (redis-rb) I am using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there isn't any proxy or balancing in redis cluster that you can control. In Redis Cluster nodes don't proxy commands to the right node in charge for a given key, but instead, they redirect clients to the right nodes serving a given portion of the keyspace. So you can't somehow control this from config.

Maybe your case with `MULTI EXEC` will be handled by the client library because it knows all about redis master nodes config

Comment: Because we know the master address, we can direct write queries to this master, but for read I want to be able to switch between master and slave depending on availability of the node.

Comment: But how would you control availability of the nodes? Only your code or the client could know which master server is executing `MULTI EXEC` query right now. I don't know any options to get this information from redis cluster.